# Elevation no showing properly on cardview

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, cardview, elevation

I have the below xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data></data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainHolder_CL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/preview_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@color/mcorner_page_background" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="@style/HomeScreenTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="@string/screen_title_corners"
        app:addWindowInsetMarginTop="@{true}"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cornerPeace"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/otherCorners"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="15dp">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/peaceImg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bottom_nav_home_new" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="header"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/peaceImg" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/desc"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="description"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/separator"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/separator"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:alpha="0.1"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/mins"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/desc"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/desc" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/mins"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="minutes"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/otherCorners"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        app:addBottomNavigationHeightMarginBottom="@{true}"
        app:addWindowInsetMarginBottom="@{true}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/corner1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:cardElevation="10dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/corner2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/challengeImg"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bottom_nav_home_new" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/challengesTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="corner 1"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/challengeImg" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/corner2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:cardElevation="10dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/corner3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/corner1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/humourImg"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bottom_nav_home_new" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="corner 2"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    app:fontFamily="@font/font_regular"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/humourImg" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/corner3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:cardElevation="10dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/corner2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/thoughtImg"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bottom_nav_home_new" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="corner 3"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    app:fontFamily="@font/font_regular"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/thoughtImg" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

This is the output I get
[image]

As you see I applied the elevation to corner 1,2 and 3 but it isn't showing properly.
It seems to be getting cut-off. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I'd debug the "otherCorners" ConstraintLayout.

You seem to have set the margins of that layout in a way to make it equal to the big CardView above it. And since the first and last CardView inside the otherCorners Layout are placed directly against the borders of the parent it prob just cuts off the shadow of the elevation on the sides. Same story, different values, for the bottom.